# In C++, do the header files of virtual function return types have to be included in the class declaration?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, forward-declaration

Consider the following code:

```
class I_Clipboard 
{
public:
    virtual ~I_Clipboard () = default;

    virtual Type_A copied_ta() const = 0;
    virtual void set_copied_ta(const Type_A & ta) = 0;

    virtual Type_B copied_tb() const = 0;
    virtual void set_copied_tb(const Type_B & tb) = 0;
};
```

Do the header files of Type_A and Type_B have to be included or is it safe to forward declare those types? Note that the copied_ta() and copied_tb() functions are returning objects, not pointers to objects. Thanks.

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: if its an object: yes, if its a pointer or reference : no, you can forward declare it

Comment: @Raildex - That is incorrect. That type can be incomplete as long as the function isn't called or defined.

Comment: No, eg https://godbolt.org/z/dMfdjnaon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types used as return type or parameter type in a function declaration (whether `virtual` or not) need to only be complete at the definition of the function (or its call site), not at its declaration. So yes, you can forward-declare them.

There is an exception if the return type from a declaration of an overriding `virtual` function differs from that of the function that it overrides. This can happen for covariant return types where the overridden function returns a pointer/reference to a class `B` and the overriding function returns a pointer/reference to a class `D` inherited from `B`. In that case `D` in the covariant return type must be complete already at the declaration (or be the class containing the overriding function), for the obvious reason that it must be checked whether the return type is really covariant.